# Calling glLoadIdentity shows awkward behaviour

Tags: opengl, graphics, glut

I have written this piece of code in c to draw a planet system with a sun and a planet

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
glPushMatrix();
glutWireSphere(1.0, 20, 16);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef((GLfloat) year ,0.0,1.0,0.0);
glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef((GLfloat) day, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glutWireSphere(0.2, 10, 8);
glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

But when I compile and run the code, second sphere is not in the view. After I increase the value of y, it appears for half of the rotation when it is behind the centre sphere and then goes out of View again, also the size of the sphere is larger than expected. if I comment out the call to glLoadIdentity(), everything works fine. As much as I know, glLoadIdentity() loads the current Matrix(ModelView_Matrix) with an identity matrix so that the effect of all the translations and rotations is reversed but why in this case the objects drawn when its called are in different manner when no rotations or transformations are being performed before its call?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is related to the way you make use of `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` in conjunction with `glLoadIdentity`:

Suppose you have some matrix **A** on your modelview stack. Now you use `glPushMatrix`, essentially saving **A** to restore it later. Inside the push-pop block, you tell GLUT to draw a sphere, which it dutyfully does, using the previously mentioned modelview matrix **A**.

If you now call `glLoadIdentity`, anything that **A** was before, is gone until you call `glPopMatrix`, which restores the previous state of **A**.

So in short, transformation calls after `glLoadIdentity` are based on the identity matrix rather than the matrix state previous to `glPushMatrix`.

Seeing that what you want to do is drawing a solar system. It'd probably be best to do something like:

```
glPushMatrix();
    /* Transformations positioning the sun */
    /* Draw the sun */
    glPushMatrix();
        /* Transformations for getting from the sun to the planet */
        /* Draw the planet */
    glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
```

As an aside, the fixed-function pipeline (glTranslate, glRotate, glPushMatrix, ...) has been deprecated for quite a while now (about 10 years?), so I'd suggest picking up OpenGL using a more [modern approach](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/).

**Edit:**

While re-reading the question, another thing struck my attention:

Assuming `year` is designating where the planet is in its revolution around the sun and `day` specifies how much the plant is rotated around its own polar axis, the correct order of transformations would be:

1. Rotate by `day` around the y-axis
2. Translate
3. Rotate by `year` around the y-axis

(Right now, you're doing it the opposite way, which could explain the strange behaviour you're experiencing. See also [here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name2).)

According to the comment by JasonD, your transformation order was right in the first place, but still it won't hurt to know about the background. ;)

Comment: I would have moved the last aside to the beginning. The new OpenGL with shaders and stuff is so much more fun and powerful.

Comment: Totally! Besides that, there's not even more effort involved learning it "properly". At least that's what I experienced.

Comment: @Zultar As no rotations and transformations are there before call to glLoadIdentity(), shouldn't the call to glLoadIdentity() have no effect on anything??

Comment: Are you sure there are no transformations present before? Maybe from different parts of your code?

Comment: Stumbled upon another issue and added explanation to my answer. Hopefully, that'll fix it!

Comment: @Zultar The transformations *are* being applied in the order you suggest, they are concatenated by GL such that they are effectively applied to the geometry in reverse order.

Comment: @JasonD Didn't know about that, can you share a link going into more detail about the process?

Comment: @Zultar It's actually explained in the link you provided yourself.

Comment: @JasonD Wow, I wasn't even aware that the old transformation calls mimicked the matrix algebra like this. I kind of grew up multiplying matrices myself in shader code. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you *do* have other transformations in the ModelView matrix. If it was already set to the identity, then loading identity would not change the behaviour.

The code you have provided only sets up a local model transform. There are no projection or view transformations being applied, so these must be done elsewhere. Perhaps at initialisation.

Without a prior view transformation, the first sphere would be drawn at the same position as the view - in other words, the camera would be inside the sphere.